# Regular Expression Help - PHP - preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hope I don't get beaten up about this. I'm new to regex and I know there are tons of resources out there, but my problem is that I want to do a few specific things and I cant seem to figure out how to piece the expression together.

Say this is a snippet of my string:

> AudienceTypes=Internal; **InternallearnerName=Ryan Litwiller;**
>   uName=227812;

I want to search for `InternallearnerName=` and store what comes after = up to the semi colon as a variable.

As an alternative to `preg_match()` I have tried to start working out a solution using `preg_split` by semicolon, `array_search()`, then `substr()` but really thought a regex would be a much simpler solution.

Comment: `InternallearnerName=([^;]*)`

Comment: WOW quick responses guys!! Much appreciated!

Comment: All very good answers, wish I could accept them all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php
$s='AudienceTypes=Internal; InternallearnerName=Ryan Litwiller; uName=227812;';
preg_match( '/\bInternallearnerName=([^;]+)/', $s, $matches );
echo $matches[1], "\n";
```

The regular expression:

- `\b` means 'word boundary', so it won't match `FOOInternallearnerName=...`
- `(`..`)` defines a group; the first pair will be number 1.
- `[^`..`]` is a single character that is NOT (`^`) one of the following; in this case `;`. So, it matches any character *except* `;`.
- `+` means 1 or more.

`$matches` will store the matches. `$matches[0]` will store the entire matched string, and `$matches[1]` the first group. (`$matches[2]` would store the second, except you only have one group `(`..`)` in the regular expression.

To match the value of `uName` aswell use this:

```
preg_match( '/\bInternallearnerName=([^;]+.*?\buName=([^;]+)/', $s, $matches );
```

Here, `$matches[2]` will be `227812`.

Note that the first and last character of the regular expression, `/` in this case, are only there to mark the beginning/ending of the regular expression. Strictly speaking they are not needed, but this is probably legacy. You can use other characters there aswell; for instance, if you're matching URLs or file paths you could use `@`:  `preg_match( "@.....@", ....)`.

Also, [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns false if there is no match, so you should check for it:

Comment: Great so if I constructed another group like this `preg_match( '/\bInternallearnerName=([^;]+)/''/\buName=([^;]+)/', $s, $matches );` would `$matches[2]` give me 227812?

Comment: Close - that would match `InternallearnerName=foo;/'buName=bar`. I updated the answer for this case.

Answer (score 1):

**Some examples**

Using `preg_match()`:

```
$text = "AudienceTypes=Internal; InternallearnerName=Ryan Litwiller; uName=227812;";
preg_match("/InternallearnerName=(.*?);/i",$text,$output);
echo $output[1];
```

Output:

```
Ryan Litwiller
```

You can use `explode()` alternatively. It's long way.

```
$text = "AudienceTypes=Internal; InternallearnerName=Ryan Litwiller; uName=227812;";
$value = explode("InternallearnerName=",$text);
$value = explode(";",$value[1]);
echo $value[0];
```

Output:

```
Ryan Litwiller
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
\bInternallearnerName=([^;]+)
```

What this means:

- find a word break (non-alphanum character)
- find **InternallearnerName=** anywhere in the string
- start a tagged match (eg: capture text) **(**
- find one-or-more **+** characters from the set **[ ]** that does not **^** contain a semi-colon **;**
- end the tagged match **)**

Note that this fails for:

```
InternallearnerName=;
```

If you care about that case, change the **+** (one-or-more) to a * (zero-or-more)

Answer (score 0):

Work in steps:

1. Use `explode(",", $string);`: this creates an array. Its entries should look like: `{[0]=> "AudienceTypes=Internal", [1]=>" InternallearnerName=Ryan Litwiller"} ...`. Notice the spaces. Try to clean them out.
2. Go on every array item, and split it again, just like before. Then, make use of the `explode()` function again, this time `explode("=", $array[$arrayItemNum]);`.

See the [PHP Manual `explode()` page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for more detailed info.